# How do I use a cell value, assigned to a variable, in a filepath string?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open an Excel spreadsheet within a changing location. The variables are the dates and file name:

C:\Reports\2019\09. September 2019\10 September 2019\1. Client reports\Report_20190911.csv

I have tried using variables, referencing to specific cells within a workbook to add the dates that are changing on a daily, monthly, and yearly basis.

Example:

> Today - C:\Reports\2019\09. September 2019\10 September 2019\1. Client reports\Report_20190911.csv
>
> Tomorrow - C:\Reports\2019\09. September 2019\11 September 2019\1. Client reports\Report_20190912.csv

I cannot seem to add an image of my referenced excel cells so I will describe it (all the cells are formula driven for the date):

```
Cell B4 - 10/09/2019 
Cell B6 - 2019
Cell B7 - 09. September 2019
Cell B9 - 10 September 2019
```

Below is my code:

```
Sub Client_Reports()

Dim year_ As Integer
year_ = Cells(6, 2)

Dim month_ As String
month_ = Cells(7, 2)

Dim date_ As Date
date_ = Cells(9, 2)

Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String

FileName = "Report_" & Format(Range("B4") + 1, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"

FilePath = "C:\Reports\year_\month_\date_\1. Client reports\FileName"

Workbooks.Open (FilePath)

End Sub
```

It searches for **C:\Reports\year_\month_\date_\1. Client reports\Report_20190911.csv**

Comment: Move the variables outside the quotes and concatenate with the ampersand: `FilePath = "C:\Reports\" & year_ & "\" & month_ ....`

Comment: The answer to your problem is found in the `FileName = ...` line.  You need to remove the vba variables from inside the quotes and concatenate them back in, like you did in that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments you should write the following:

`FilePath = "C:\Reports\" & year_ & "\" & month_ & "\" & date_ & "\1. Client reports\" & FileName`

Never put a variable's name inside double quotes when you want to build a string expression. It's like typing its name as a string, you are not referencing to the actual variable.

Comment: I have now successfully sourced the files with the date variables. However, it seems to have an issue with the formatting of the file I open through VBA. Ex., if I normally open the file, it has a column with the date dd/mm/yyyy, but when opened with the macro, it changes to mm/dd/yyyy. Could this be due to the fact that the file I am attempting to open is csv?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing it, but it seems like this has to do with the difference between how dates are formatted in your system, and how are formatted in vba (american system).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Client_Reports()

    Dim MyDate As Date
    MyDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Range("B4") 'change MySheet to the sheet name holding the date

    Dim MonthName As String
    MonthName = Format(MyDate, "mmmm") 'this takes the month name

    Dim MonthNumber As String
    MonthNumber = Format(MyDate, "mm") 'this takes the month number with 2 digits

    Dim DayNumber As String
    DayNumber = Format(MyDate, "dd") 'this takes the day number with 2 digits, switch to "d" for 1 digit.

    Dim FilePath  As String
    FilePath = "C:\Reports\" & Year(MyDate) & "\" & MonthNumber & ". " & MonthName & "\" & DayNumber & " " & MonthName & _
        " " & Year(MyDate) & "\1. Client reports\"

    Dim FileName
    FileName = "Report_" & Format(MyDate, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & FileName)

End Sub
```

This way you only need the cell **B4** everything else can be done just with that.